# Воспроизведение видеопотока по ссылке

Tags: java, android, видео, потоки-данных, videoview

Получаю такого рода ссылку из базы tcp://62.109.15.84:1300. Как можно воспроизвести данный видеопоток

видео передается в формате mpeg-ts, кодеки h.264 и mpeg layer II

Воспроизвожу таким методом

```
public void play(String address){
            final Uri path = Uri.parse(address);
            videoView.setVideoURI(path);

            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                      Log.d("START VIDEO", "start Uri");
                      videoView.start();
                  }
              });
    }
```

Comment: А чем он вообще воспроизводится, если опустить Android? Никто же не знает, что там за данные.

Comment: mpeg-ts, кодеки h.264 и mpeg layer II

Comment: Попробуй воспользоваться вот этим - https://github.com/VideoExpertsGroup/RTSPPlayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данную проблему смог решить с помощью библиотеки https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_surface_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical"
        tools:ignore="true">
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/player_surface"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="360dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

```
      public void play(String address) {
          mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) globalView.findViewById(R.id.player_surface);
          mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

          mSurfaceFrame = (FrameLayout) globalView.findViewById(R.id.player_surface_frame);
          mMediaUrl = new String(address);

          try {
              mLibVLC = new LibVLC();
              mLibVLC.setAout(mLibVLC.AOUT_AUDIOTRACK);
              mLibVLC.setVout(mLibVLC.VOUT_ANDROID_SURFACE);
              mLibVLC.setHardwareAcceleration(LibVLC.HW_ACCELERATION_FULL);

              mLibVLC.init(getContext());
          } catch (LibVlcException e){
              Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
          }

          mSurface = mSurfaceHolder.getSurface();
          mLibVLC.attachSurface(mSurface, VideoStreamFragment.this);
          mLibVLC.playMRL(mMediaUrl);
     }
```